# What does the pub/static/.htaccess file do in magento2.4

Tags: magento2

What does pub/static/.htaccess do in magento2.4 and can I delete it? Does it have anything to do with apache and nothing to do with nignx

Answer (score 3):

`pub/static/.htaccess` is responsible for rewriting static view files for Apache, it does nothing for Nginx.

So, if you are using Nginx, you can delete this file, otherwise, it will be caused unable to load static content in Apache.